# Creating a vector of vectors to be used in a class and plotted using CERNROOT

Tags: c++, class, vector, root-framework

I'm new to programming and wish to create a class or header (I'm honestly unsure of what it is like I said, beginner physicist, trying to make use of my free time, but I assume it's a header file seeing as the definition of the soon to be mentioned object will be in it).
I'm having problems creating a vector of vectors. I thought it was done something like this:

```
    #include <array>
    #include <vector>


    constexpr int MaxIterations = 101;
    constexpr double aprox_PI = 3.141592653589793238463;

    using PiArray = std::array<double, MaxIterations>;
    using PiMatrix = std::array<PiArray, MaxIterations>;
    using PiVector = std::vector<std::vector<double>> ; //here lies the problem, the ones above work fine.

    class MonteCarloPiCalculator{
        //some stuff goes in here, like function declarations. The definitions are in another file
    }
```

So the size and contents of the vector can be added later, but can also be defined beforehand. This is how the graphing tool I use.

```
auto* gr4 = new TGraph(calc.VectPot.data(), calc.relDiff.data());
```

From the ROOT TGraph file I found this:

```
TGraph(const TVectorF &vx, const TVectorF &vy); 
TGraph(const TVectorD &vx, const TVectorD &vy);
```

Which would mean that I can use vectors with float and double values in them. 
Even before compiling I get this message in Visual Studio:

> no instance of constructor matches the argument list  argument types
>   are: (const std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>> *, const
>   std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>> *)

How would I go about fixing this issue? I would appreciate any help I can get. 
Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: First comment: usually in C++ we avoid as much as possible raw pointers, in favor of smart pointers: shared_ptr, weak_ptr and unique_ptr.

Comment: Also, to make it possible to troubleshot your problem, it would be great to have a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The error just state that you are trying to construct an object with wrong type of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

> TGraph(const TVectorD &vx, const TVectorD &vy);

These are references to TVectorD, not raw pointers.

Comment: Yes, that was my thought as well after reading the error. Do you maybe have an idea of how to modify the vector of vectors' definition to work in this case? Also thanks for the tip about reproducible examples, I'll try to make something!

Comment: I have fixed the issue. I simply used my array format instead of the vector format. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Basically you need to match your arguments to the constructor and what is defined in the constructor. If `TVectorD` is an std::array, you either need to use std::array or add a constructor for std::vector. It's difficult to say more without viewing your code.

Comment: Thank you again! I've used the array instead of vector   after seeing your comment yesterday. It works as intended now.